# Laravel/Eloquent: Como criar chave primária composta por duas chaves estrangeiras?

Tags: banco-de-dados, laravel, laravel-eloquent, chave-primária, chave-composta

Estou criando um sistema simples para gestão escolar e terei uma tabela denominada 'turma_alunos', onde a chave primária deve ser composta pelo id do aluno e id da turma, que são chaves estrangeiras das tabelas 'alunos' e 'turmas' respectivamente.
Criei minha migration da seguinte forma:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('turma_alunos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('ID_TURMA_TUR')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('ID_TURMA_TUR')->references('ID_TURMA_TUR')->on('turmas');
        $table->integer('ID_ALUNO_ALU')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('ID_ALUNO_ALU')->references('ID_ALUNO_ALU')->on('alunos');
        $table->primary(['ID_TURMA_TUR', 'ID_ALUNO_ALU']);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

No fim foi criada a tabela com a chave primária composta, porém apenas o id do aluno ficou como sendo chave estrangeira:

[image: Tabela criada após rodar a migration]

É possível fazer isso da maneira como eu gostaria? Como fazer isso no Laravel?

Comment: Eu resolvi colocar uma resposta, talvez isso ajude a entender que foi criado as relações corretamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A chave em **amarelo** no [phpmyadmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/) significa ***chave primária*** da sua tabela, a chave em **cinza** significa um ***índice***, exemplo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
>   para saber se foi criado as relações corretamente

e para saber se foi realmente criado as relações só clicar em `Relation view`:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e tem que aparecer as duas relações (*exemplo fictício*) como esse exemplo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

assim está correto, sendo elas como chaves primárias dessa tabelas com relações em outras tabelas.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Está correto então a criação. O que seria exatamente esse índice?

Comment: @Matheus [leitura recomendada](https://imasters.com.br/desenvolvimento/sql-server-chaves-primarias-versus-indices-clusterizados/?trace=1519021197&source=single)